# Is there an equivalent of the bullet gem in Rails for Ecto/Phoenix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've found the [bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) to be an incredibly useful tool for catching slow database queries in Rails apps. Is there a similar tool for `Ecto`/`Phoenix` that helps notify you of N+1 and other slow queries?

Answer (score 6):

`N+1` queries don't happen in `Ecto`.

Ecto associations must be explicitly loaded in the query using [preload](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3)

If you try to access an association that has not yet been loaded, it will be an instance of [Ecto.Association.NotLoaded](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Association.NotLoaded.html#content)

As for other slow queries, you can add a custom logger to ecto:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  url: {:system, "DATABASE_URL"},
  loggers: [{Ecto.LogEntry, :log, []}, {MyApp.CustomLogger, :log, []}]
```

Custom Logger:

```
defmodule MyApp.CustomLogger do
  def log(entry) do
    if (entry.query_time > 1000_000) do
      Logger.info("Slow!!!!: #{entry.query}")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you my own gem [ecto_profiler](https://github.com/DmitryKK/ecto_profiler)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18634357)

Comment: @JessBowers How can I include the essential parts from the large and thick gem? neurodynamic asks for an analogue of bullet!! Not part of code! It is poor quality and irresponsible Review

Comment: Yeah i see what you mean. But if you think it's a bad question for SO (a 'shopping question' which really doesn't fit the SO rules for good questions), in that case don't answer, vote the question down. Or try to edit the Q to make it better. I'm only trying to help you use the site, no trying to offend -- and i'm only one voter.